# When a question is closed as off-topic the FAQ link should take to the page showing which questions are on-topic

Tags: bug, closed-questions, off-topic

I closed a question as off-topic, and the closure message is the following one:

> Questions on Drupal Answers are expected to relate to drupal within the scope defined in the [FAQ](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq). Consider editing the question or leaving comments for improvement if you believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope. Read more about [closed questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#close) here.

The first link takes to the [Help center](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/helpcenter). IMO, it should take to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/on-topic) which is the page that shows the list of allowed topics, once visible in the top of the FAQ page.

The second link should also be updated to point at [the page that explains what closed questions are](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/closed-questions).

Comment: That's because the link is still `http://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq` - i.e. the old one. The second link is also the old one - `http://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#close` and needs updating as well. Therefore this is actually a bug.

Comment: The same is true of the moderator message templates. I need to report that as a separate bug.

Comment: The second link is already redirected to `http://drupal.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/closed-questions`. At least that is what happens to me on Drupal Answers; I think every user is redirected there too. Clearly, instead of using the old link and then redirecting users to the new link, it would be better to use the new link.

Comment: Ah. I just looked at the link rather than actually following it :)